# MongoDB aggregate to filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this aggregate in Python working without 0 issues

```js
mycol.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'Extention': '100',
            'FinalUnicode': {
            '$ne': ''
        }
    }
}
```

I am now working with NodeJS and Express. I have this so far but can't seem to give it the `FinalUnicode` filter. Currently it works by returning the `Extentions` that are equal to 100.

```
query = { "Extention": { $eq: filters["ext"] } }
```

Comment: you can write the same code in nodejs, and [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/v4.1/fundamentals/aggregation/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()` like this:

```js
mycol.find({ Extention: '100', FinalUnicode: { $ne: '' }});
```

Or you can literally **copy/paste** aggregation code that you have in Python.